# I keep getting an error, IndexError: list assignment index out of range, after the code finishes editing the text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to put the line number next to the text in the file but after it finishes it shows an error. why? also, not sure it shows, but in import.txt, there has to be an empty line after the last on with text for some reason.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    replace_line("import.txt",(count),(whole))
  File "main.py", line 10, in replace_line
    lines[line_num] = text
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Code:

```
import time, sys, random, os
count = -1
read = open("import.txt","r")
while input("Press Enter to continue...") != "End":
  open("import.txt",'r').close()
  os.system('clear')
  ask = input("Type run: ")
  def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
      lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
      lines[line_num] = text
      edt = open(file_name,'w')
      edt.writelines(lines)
      edt.close()
  if ask == "run" or ask == "Run":
    for line in read:
      count += 1
      prefix = ("["+str((count)+1)+"] ")
      if (prefix) not in line:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        whole = (str(prefix)+str(line))
        replace_line("import.txt",(count),(whole))
      else:
        continue
    open("import.txt",'r').close()
```

Import.txt
*before*

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

Import.txt
*after*

```
[1] Test 1
[2] Test 2
[3] Test 3
```

Comment: Which line precisely is the error happening on? Is it `lines[line_num] = text`? If so, which line are you trying to replace? It's possible that the given `line_num` is greater than the total number of lines in the file, which would make this error happen.

Comment: i dont know, but i just updated it, now it shows the whole error, not sure if it helps tho

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get your code to work, is to change `lines[line_num] = text` to `lines[line_num - 1] = text` and start `count` at `0`. The reason for this is that, `count` keeps increasing and is always 1 ahead of the index you really want to replace.

A tangent ... 
I would highly advice opening this file only once, processing each line, and then writing once. At the moment you are opening the file *at least* 5 times in your code. This is not only inefficient, but will make debugging harder. In fact, you don't even need user interaction here, right? I would consider just modularizing this further. All you really need is the readlines() function, a custom modification function, and then a writelines() function.

Here is one implementation of what I am thinking:

```
file_name = 'import.txt'
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

new_lines = []
for count, line in enumerate(data):
    new_line = '[{}] {}'.format(count + 1, line)
    new_lines.append(new_line)

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    data = f.writelines(new_lines)
```

Comment: i still get the error but this time import.txt has  `[2] Test 1
[3] Test 2
[4] Test 3`

Comment: Good point! Unfortunately, this will require some shotgun surgery to resolve as you are incrementing count is a couple spots (adding 1 to count while building the prefix). My hunch is that the file is also being corrupted since you aren't closing before doing another open. I've updated my answer with a solution I think may guide you in a more stable direction. Feel free to comment, but IMO that might be the best way forward.